# Python Class - Methods

Tags: python

So I am trying to create a program that has a class called "Loan" which calculates the monthly payment and total payment of a car with data fields. I'm guessing that my error is caused by having a method ( getMonthlyPayment() ) in the method ( getTotalPayment ). How do I put a method inside a method? Or is there another solution to my problem?

Thanks!
My error is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\ericl_000\Desktop\Python\HW 5 ( Python ).py", line 38, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "C:\Users\ericl_000\Desktop\Python\HW 5 ( Python ).py", line 37, in main
>     print("The total payment is ", loan.getTotalPayment())
>   File "C:\Users\ericl_000\Desktop\Python\HW 5 ( Python ).py", line 27, in getTotalPayment
>     return getMonthlyPayment * self.__NumYearsLoans * 12
> NameError: name 'getMonthlyPayment' is not defined
> >>>
> ```

```
  class Loan:
    def __init__(self, AnnIntRate = 1.0, NumYearsLoans = 1.0, LoanAmt = 1.0, BoName = " "):
        self.__AnnIntRate = AnnIntRate
        self.__NumYearsLoans = NumYearsLoans
        self.__LoanAmt = LoanAmt
        self.__BoName = BoName
    def getAnnIntRate(self):
        return self.__AnnIntRate
    def getNumYearsLoans(self):
        return self.__NumYearsLoans
    def getLoanAmt(self):
        return self.__LoanAmt
    def getBoName(self):
        return self.__BoName
    def setAnnIntRate(self,AnnIntRate):
        self.__AnnIntRate = AnnIntRate
    def setNumYearsLoans(self,NumYearsLoans):
        self.__NumYearsLoans = NumYearsLoans
    def setLoanAmt(self,LoanAmt):
        self.__LoanAmt = LoanAmt
    def setBoName(self,BoName):
        self.__BoName = BoName
    def getMonthlyPayment(self):
        monthlyIntRate = self.__AnnIntRate / 1200
        return self.__LoanAmt * monthlyIntRate / ( 1 - ( 1 / ( 1 + monthlyIntRate) ** ( self.__NumYearsLoans * 12 )))
    def getTotalPayment(self):
        return getMonthlyPayment() * self.__NumYearsLoans * 12
    def main():
        YearlyIntRate = float(input("Enter yearly interest rate, for example, 7.25: "))
        NumOfYears = float(input("Enter number of years as an integer: "))
        LoanAmount = float(input("Enter loan amount, for example, 120000.95: "))
        BorrowerName = input("Enter a borrow's name: ")
        loan = Loan(YearlyIntRate,NumOfYears,LoanAmount,BorrowerName)
        print("The loan is for ", loan.getBoName())
        print("The monthly payment is ", loan.getMonthlyPayment())
        print("The total payment is ", loan.getTotalPayment())
    main()
```

Comment: Bean-style getters and setters in Python? The horror! Also, you're missing `self.` before accessing instance methods. Python is explicit.

Comment: Thanks @Kupiakos ! :) Post it on answers so I can put as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like accessing members, you need to prepend all accesses to methods with `self.`.

Change `getTotalPayment()` to

```
return self.getMonthlyPayment() * self.__NumYearsLoans * 12
```

Also, take a look at [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to make getters and setters less painful. However, most of the time, you shouldn't even be defining getters and setters in Python. Private-ness is not usually treated as a concept in idiomatic Python.